# switch case, скорость обработки

Tags: java, switch

Пишу текстовый квест на джава, пока лучшая идея по сохранениям это switch case level. Но возникает вопрос про скорость обработки данных, если массив будет состоять из 500-600 вариантов, не будет ли приложение на андроид виснуть? Какая скорость обработки данных?
Снизу код из классов которые передают нужную цифру.

```
        SharedPreferences save = getSharedPreferences("Save", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = save.edit();
    editor.putInt("Level", 0);
    editor.apply();
```

А это сам обработчик

```
   int level;
public void buttonClick1() {
    butSave.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (level) {
                        case 0:
                            try {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, go1.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } catch (Exception e) {//
                            }
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            try {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, go2.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } catch (Exception e) {  //
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            try {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, go3.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } catch (Exception e) { //
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            try {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, go4.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } catch (Exception e) { //
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
```

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен, каким образом ваш массив связан со switch/case оператором?  Вы ожидаете 500-600 меток case в вашем коде?

Comment: 500-600 вариантов - это ничто. 500-600 тысяч выриантов может иметь какую то разницу. Но писать 500-600 case в switch - это как то перебор, подумайте о замене switch-case на словарь

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Я дополнил свой вопрос кодом, для большего понимания. Подойдет ли такой вариант для реализации около 500 кейсов? Как понимаю, моя реализация плоха только в читабельности кода но это не повлияет на скорость работы приложения?

 Я пытался сделать через словарь, но не получались сами переходы внутрь класса, я только учусь программированию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вам порекомендовали через словарик:

Где-нибудь его определяете:

```
Map<Integer, Class> activities = new HashMap<Integer, Class>();
activities.put(0, go0.class);
activities.put(1, go1.class);
// ...
activities.put(999, go999.class);
```

и используете:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activities.get(level));
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
} catch (Exception e) { //
}
```

Можно без словарика, через получение класса по его названию, например:

```
try {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.change.go" + level);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, clazz);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
} catch (Exception e) { //
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Я попробовал ваш метод через словарь, он намного удобнее и читабельнее. Но я допустил где-то ошибку, почему-то переходы на нужную мне страницу по метке (level) передаются на одну меньше (level -1), проблему я смог решить только поменяв в уровнях метку передачи и сделав наоборот (level+1) и тогда переходы верно работают. Да, это решение работает но хотелось бы разобраться в моей ошибке.

Comment: `Map<Integer, Class> activities = new HashMap<Integer, Class>();
        activities.put(0, go1.class);
        activities.put(1, go2.class);
        activities.put(2, go3.class); ` 

Но класс go3 передает метку не 2, а 3 и код работает и переводит в нужную страницу go3.

Comment: Вы можете использовать любой ключ в мапе, нумерация не обязательно должна начинаться с нуля, например совершенно спокойно можно сделать так: `activities.put(123456, go1.class);`